# Wordpress - Parent/child - How to create the link in front editing situation?

Tags: wordpress, forms, parent-child, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

Here is the situation:

I am working on a Wordpress-driven site 
on which front-end users should be able to create Authors 
and once on the Author's page, 
add Books that the Author has written.

To do so:

1. I have created two custom content classes (Author, Book)
2. I have used the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to create a 1-to-many relationship between the two. The field is a custom field of the Author, listing the Books that Author is "related" to
3. I have used User Submitted Post Pro plugin to create the two forms needed. The first to create a Author and the second, placed within the Author detail page, to add a Book.

My issue is double:

1. How do I pass the Author id to the Book creation form?
2. How do I, upon creation of a new Book, update the relationship field of the corresponding Author?

I am also willing to hear I am taking this the wrong way.
Your input is very welcome.
Thank you.

Axel

Answer (score 0):

*(I am not providing the code in this answer, but can write it if required)*

Because this is a 1 to many relationship between author and Book here is the best way to achieve this  -

1. Create a custom Taxonomy called "book_author".
2. Create a custom post Type "Books" and link the taxonomy 'book_author' to it.
3. Create custom front end form to create the new Authors (Taxonomy terms) in Book Authors (Custom Taxonomy)
4. Create a front end form to create Books (custom post).
5. When the Create Author form is submitted and author is created redirect the user to create book form with the author_id (term_id) in url. something like http://example.com/create-book/?author_id=1
6. Use this author Id to associate the book with it. You can use this wordpress function to associate a custom post with a term https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms